# Powershell: Access denied error received when executing Recieve-Job

Tags: powershell, nagios

I have a small powershell script that I want to execute via Nagios monitoring for verification if a certain directory exists yes or no. When debugging and/or running the script in the Powershell ISE, every thing is OK and the desired result is produced. When scheduling the script via Nagios, I'm receiving "access denied" errors.

Lines in the script that produce the error:

```
$testJob = Start-Job -scriptblock {test-path $($args[0])} -credential $ipmamCredentials -argumentlist $ipmamdir
$finished = Wait-Job $testJob
$result = Receive-Job $testJob
```

Errors produced in Nagios:

```
Receive-Job : [localhost] There is an error launching the background process. Error reported: Access is denied.
At C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_ipmam_drives.ps1:19 char:26
+ $result = Receive-Job <<<< $testJob 
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (:) [Receive-Job], PSRemotingTransportException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: Does the process running Nagios have permission to the folder you're checking for?

Comment: Nagios should have access to thet folder due to the credentials passed in the Start-Job call. That is exactly the reason why I'm using Start-Job. Normal access users (including Nagios) cannot access the folder directly. Only the privileged user can access that folder.

Comment: I'm assuming Nagios is running as a service? Looking at the error more closely, it looks like its coming from starting the job, suggesting the service doesn't have enough rights to perform impersonation / elevation.

Comment: Values from the "Log On" TAB for the Nagios service: is started automatically at system boot using the Local System Account. Flag "Allow service to interact with desktop" is set.